# A book from the 70s-80s about a young man (Kevin?) with goat hooves who makes special boots to hide his deformity

Tags: story-identification, books

A book from the 70s-80s about a young man with goat hooves who makes special boots to hide his deformity.

Young man's name is Kevin? Kelvin? Kev something.

Comment: Hi there! That's a bit terse as of now; could you please take a look at [these guidelines](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they trigger any more memories you could [edit] in, such as the language it was written in, what the cover looked like, anything more from the plot (including spoilers), etc, etc. Everything might help tracking it down :)

Comment: @closevoters I'll agree that this question is terse, but "too broad"? If you're going to vote to close, please quote, say, 3-4 books 1) written in the 70s-80s 2) main character having a Kev-something name 3) said character having goat hooves. Then it'll be too broad. Otherwise, **voted to leave open**.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image]

**[THE CRYSTAL GRYPHON](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2957)** by Andre Norton (1972)

Kerovan is the rightful heir to the throne of Ulm, but is shunned because his feet are  cloven hooves. He hides this with special boots.

He is forced to flee when Ulm is invaded by raiders. He travels to the land where his betrothed lady Joisan lives, only to find that a scoundrel has stolen his identity and seeks to marry her.

But the two must join to defeat the dark magic that threatens the lands.